# Primefaces commandButton ajax event set hide dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 5.1. In my project commandButton onclick to open the dialog is work fine.Button in testAction I try to hide dialog but it not working.

**detail.xhtml**

```
<p:commandButton value="test" action="#{stud.testAction}" ajax="false" onclick="PF('waitDialog').show();"/>

<p:dialog id="waitDialog" widgetVar="waitDialog">
<p:graphicImage url="#{stud.waitImage}"/>
</p:dialog>
```

**detail.java**

```
public void testAction()
{
downloadMethod(toList)
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance.execute("PF('waitDialog').hide()");
}
```

My doubt how to hide dialog when set commandButton attribute ajax false.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute JavaScript on client side within an non ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28992337/execute-javascript-on-client-side-within-an-non-ajax-call)

Comment: if you are trying to do a download, the possible duplicate is correct

Comment: Hey, I didn't test your code but I got a question on it. If you put a return String for the method doesn't it reload the page upon method completion (so that the wait dialog should be closed anyway) ?